# In Go why can we use *os.File as a parameter in bufio.NewScanner when the definition suggests, it should only accept io.Reader?

Tags: file, go, types

Trying to learn Go and been using `bufio.NewScanner` to read contents of a file. I do this using the following code:

```
input_file, err := os.Open("input.txt")

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(input_file)
//do stuff
```

Thought I would look at the definition and saw something strange (well at least to me), `os.Open("input.txt")` above actually returns a `*os.File` and `bufio.NewScanner` expects a `io.Reader` as a parameter. `Reader` is an interface and `File` is a struct that does not implement the interface or anything like that if that's even possible.

But looks like this is totally fine. Am I missing something about how go works? I have a C# background and to me the parameters are of different types so the compiler shouldn't allow that, right?

Was just curious and wasn't sure where else to ask this.

Comment: *`File` is a struct that does not implement the interface* - You just eliminated the correct answer yourself.

Comment: If you’re interested in Go, going through the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour) will give you a overview of the basics like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[os.File](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Read) is actually implementing the [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) interface.

Which mean it implement all method with same signature provided by io.Reader interface.

In occurence in this particular case, this method:

```
func (f *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```

Comment: What's easiest way to find this documented? Except going through all source  code?